# How do I test a Firebase Cloud Function that expects a user ID?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a number of Firebase Cloud Functions that require a user ID token to take actions on behalf of that user.

I'm attempting to write local integration tests. This requires that I pass a user ID token to my cloud function. However, I can't find any Firebase APIs that will allow me to generate a legitimate user ID token within the test suite.

Does anyone know how to generate a legitimate user ID token to test cloud functions?

Note: a "custom token" is not a "user ID token" and will not work in this case.

I'm also curious, if generating such a token is not possible using Firebase APIs, how are people out there writing integration tests for the cloud functions that are based on the logged-in user.